# Android: How long to write a text file to storage?

Tags: php, android, file, upload

Within an `Activity` in my `Android Application` I am attempting to  upload 4 `text files` from the `storage on device` to a server using a `PHP script`.

These files are generated in the previous activity whilst playing a game.

However when I try to upload them i get the following exception message from my code:

`"Source file not exist"` then it shows the path to the filename that should of been uploaded

I know that the files are being properly generated as I can see them on the devices storage. I also know that the upload to server functionality works as I have tested it with a file that was created a few days ago.

Basically I am wondering:

Are the files `fully created` in previous activity before the next activity tries to upload them?  I.e. `how long` does it take to write to storage?

Would **delaying the thread** that carries out upload functionality solve the problem?

**Activity where files are uploaded: (note: file names passed as intent extras to next activity)**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mathsgameresults);

        initialiseVars();
        setAllTextViews();

         messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mathsresultsservertext);

            messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/storage/sdcard0/files/"+fileNameRaw
                    +"','/storage/sdcard0/ files/"+fileNameEEGPower+"','/storage/sdcard0/files/"+fileNameMeditation+"','/storage/sdcard0/files/"+fileNameAttention+"' ");

            //url to php script on server
            upLoadServerUri = " my url in here (not shown)";

            //remove this if not wanted to show.
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MathsGameResults.this, "", "Uploading files...", true);

            //logic to upload files in new thread
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });                      

                     uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + fileNameRaw);                       
                     uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + fileNameEEGPower);                       
                     uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + fileNameMeditation);                       
                     uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + fileNameAttention);                       

                }
              }).start();     




    }

 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


              final String fileName = sourceFileUri;

              HttpURLConnection conn = null;
              DataOutputStream dos = null;  
              String lineEnd = "\r\n";
              String twoHyphens = "--";
              String boundary = "*****";
              int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
              byte[] buffer;
              int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
              final File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 



              if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                   dialog.dismiss(); 

                   Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                        + sourceFileUri);

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                                    + fileName);
                       }
                   }); 

                   return 0;

              }
              else
              {
                   try { 

                         // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                       FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                       URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                       // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                       conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                       conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                       conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                       conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                       conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                       dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                       dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                                 + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                       // create a buffer of  maximum size
                       bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                       bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                       buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                       // read file and write it into form...
                       bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                       while (bytesRead > 0) {

                         dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                         bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                         bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                         bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                        }

                       // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                       dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                       dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                       // Responses from the server (code and message)
                       serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                       final String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                       Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                               + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                       //server responsecode 200 means upload successful
                       if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    String msg = serverResponseMessage  + "File Upload Completed.\n\n "

                                                  +fileName;

                                    messageText.setText(msg);

                                    Boolean isDel =  sourceFile.delete();

                                    if(isDel)
                                    {
                                    Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this, "File Upload Complete. And Deleted.", 
                                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this, "File Upload Complete. And NOT Deleted.", 
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                }
                            });                
                       }    

                       //close the streams //
                       fileInputStream.close();
                       dos.flush();
                       dos.close();

                  } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                      dialog.dismiss();  
                      ex.printStackTrace();

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                              Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      });

                      Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
                  } catch (Exception e) {

                      dialog.dismiss();  
                      e.printStackTrace();

                      final String d =  e.getMessage() + " " + e.getStackTrace();

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          public void run() {
                              messageText.setText(d + " Got Exception : see logcat ");
                              Toast.makeText(MathsGameResults.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }
                      });
                      Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                                       + e.getMessage(), e);  
                  }
                  dialog.dismiss();       
                  return serverResponseCode; 

               } // End else block 
             }
```

**EDIT:**

**Previous Activity where files are created:**

Method that creates file (all 4 are identical):

```
/**
     * Method used to save Raw data to a file on phone
     * 
     * @param data
     */
    public void writeToFileRawData(String data) {

        // creating the file where the contents will be written to
        File file = new File(dir, fileNameRaw + ".txt");

        FileOutputStream os;

        try {

            boolean append = true;

            os = new FileOutputStream(file, append);

            String writeMe = data + "\n";

            if (isHeaderDateRaw) {
                os.write(headerDateRaw.getBytes());
                isHeaderDateRaw = false;
            }

            if (isHeaderRawValues) {
                os.write(headerRawValues.getBytes());
                isHeaderRawValues = false;
            }

            os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Path were files are saved and creating file name:

```
    // code relating to saving to file
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/files/");
            dir.mkdir();
//creating file name
fileNameRaw = "MathsGame-Raw-" + timestamp + android.os.Build.SERIAL;
```

Saving data to file using handler:

```
case TGDevice.MSG_RAW_DATA:

                headerRawValues = order("Seconds") + order("Value") + "\n";

                Time time2= new Time();
                time2.setToNow();

                String seconds2 = time2.hour + ":" + (time2.minute < 10 ? "0"+time2.minute : time2.minute) + ":"
                        + (time2.second < 10 ? "0"+time2.second : time2.second);


                // creating the string to be written to file
                String line2 = order(seconds2 + "") + order("" + msg.arg1)
                        + "\n";

                // write the string to file
                writeToFileRawData(line2);

                break;
```

Passing file name to next activity via intent:

```
Intent openActivity = new Intent(
                            "com.example.brianapp.mathsgameresults");
                    //sending session results + 4 text file names to new activity
                    openActivity.putExtra("fileNameRaw", fileNameRaw);
                    startActivity(openActivity);
```

Comment: would you also post the code where you actually create the files

Comment: Please see my edit where I show the code snippets for creating a file. Note that only one file process is shown the process is the same for all 4

Comment: You showed way to much code. And even suggested that the writing thread had not finished writing before you open the second activity. Now when are you doing that?

Comment: sorry, Im not sure what you mean? The writing to file occurs in the first activity, it is the filenames that are then passed by intent to the next activity where the file uploads should occur

Comment: Yes. And when is the intent started? You still did not tell or show. You should only start the intent when the writing has finished.

Comment: The intent is started as shown in the final code block in my question? The writing is all carried out in the handler within the activity.